# MATLAB Error with Adding Gaussian Noise

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
N=1000
n=1:N;
rng(1);
s1 = 0.2;
s2 = 0.8;
w1(n) = randn(N,1)*s1
w2 = randn(N,1)*s2
subplot(1,3,1)
y=(sin(n/50)+cos(n/200)-sin(n/100))
plot(n,y(n))
subplot(1,3,2)
y1(n) = y(n) + w1;
plot(n,y1(n))
subplot(1,3,3)
y2(n) = y(n)+w2 
plot(n,y2(n))
```

This code throws an error saying that the matrix dimensions should agree. Somebody please explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

w2 is 1000x1 while y(n) is 1x1000. You have to transpose w2:

```
y2(n) = y(n)+w2.'
```